# paying for childrens apps

Tags: google-play-store

my partner has 2 google accounts. One is not widely used and has been applied to our daughters tablet. My partner has google rewards installed on her mobile and wanted to use the credit to buy DLC for one off my daughters apps. how can this done, as its 2 different accounts.

TIA